# Equivalent of above and below for the words right and left

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I am writing some computer code and I want to find the equivalent of the words above and below for the right and left, so I want a precise word rather than a whole sentence / expression. Something people would write if they use the telegraph.

I.e. "InserNodeAbove" sounds correct to me but "InserNodeRight" does not sound very nice to me. Would "rightwise" be the equivalent?

Comment: What is wrong with "InserNodeOnRight"?

Comment: Note that in both cases you have omitted the letter "t" in the word "insert".

Comment: This is an old question.  But I don't think it is on topic.  Elements of computer code are not written in English, they just have to make enough sense to help programmers remember what they do.  EG "InnerHTML" makes no sense, if you think about it (it isn't a language), but it is clear enough and acts as a helpful reminder of what the method does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left wise sounds rather odd. Having expressions like '**on/ to the left side**' and '**-hand side**' I'd suggest a concise '**to the left**' over 'on the left'; this one sounds and looks good to me.

Tad-ah:
`InsertNode.ToTheLeft`

Answer (score 2):

> "InserNodeAbove" sounds correct to me but "InserNodeRight" does not
>   sound very nice to me.

**A**

It sounds perfectly all right to me - I have no problem understanding it. It's not like you are writing a novel or need strict grammar.

Presumably in your documentation/comments there will an explanation of each of these terms.

---

**B**
Note that the term "rightwise" is (a) archaic and (b) does not mean what you think it means.

> rightwise - “righteous, just; right, justifiable”
>   https://www.yourdictionary.com/rightwise)

---

**C**

You probably mean, "rightward".

> adverb Also right·wards. toward or on the right.
>
> adjective situated on
>   the right. directed toward the right.
>   https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rightward

Answer (score 1):

I think aright and [aleft](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aleft) are the words you are looking for.

The definition of the aright as `on the right` is hard to find.

###### Update:

Below are two links from wiktionary.

> [aleft](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aleft)
>
> 1. (archaic) To or on the left-hand side.

> [aright](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aright)
>
> 1. Rightly, correctly; in the right way or form.
> 2. (archaic) To or on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function acts with respect to an "anchor" node (to the left of *it*, to the right of *it*) you could also use verbs to express a similar idea:

AnchorNode.PrependNode

AnchorNode.AppendNode

P.S.  That said, the idea of nodes being to the left or to the right is strange to me. I've never encountered it.